# Line Endings AutoDetect in Windows and Linux

Tags: git

I've seen this question asked a lot, and I've read through the material on it.

I'm still confused, and I've come across some conflicting opinions.

In my environment, development happens on both Windows and Linux machines. The files in question have no extension, but contain text, and are required to have LF endings to comply on the Linux side.

I want to create a .gitattributes file so that only one change is necessary, centrally.

I'm specifying all files as binary (such as image and audio) to avoid every single file being converted, as well as creating rules for other files.

I've seen advise on using:

```
* text=auto
```

According to another stack overflow post here:

> Here's what * text=auto does in my words: when someone commits a file,
>   Git guesses whether that file is a text file or not, and if it is, it
>   will commit a version of the file where all CR + LF bytes are replaced
>   with LF bytes. It doesn't directly affect what files look like in the
>   working tree, there are other settings that will convert LF bytes to
>   CR + LF bytes when checking out a file.

This seems wrong for my purposes.

When the repository is cloned from a Linux machine, and a branch checked out, it sounds like it will convert it to CRLF in the working directory.

Do the line endings in the working directory depend on the OS? Does it autodetect?

I need it to be LF in the working directory on Linux. On Windows I don't much care. But it needs to be LF on both Linux and in the remote repository

Will `* text=auto` accomplish what I'm looking for?

Would `* text=auto eol=lf` work better for my purposes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer, but the usual trick used here is to have Git automatically convert line endings to the appropriate form for the particular client system (CRLF for Windows, LF for Linux).  While doing local development, you will perceive that you have the right line endings, and then Git under the hood will handle converting them to whatever their original form is on the remote server.

Comment: What would be the .gitattributes notation for that? I haven't seen a clear answer as to whether text=auto make choices based on OS. It sounds like it defaults to CRLF in the working directory, regardless of the OS

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on `git help attributes` you should use the last thing you said:

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

From the documentation:

```
Set to string value "lf"
   This setting forces Git to normalize line endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file is checked out.
```

Comment: After attempting this, I've verified that it does not force LF in the working directory. A file committed in CRLF throws the notification "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in Another.txt" The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.